# RegEx match group that don't contain sequence

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to write a Python regex that does matches a group only if it doesn't contain a certain string.

Consider the following strings:

```
   VOID ALL               $-11.20
   CANCEL                  $-6.00
   -10.00% LP              $-0.25
   LOYALTY CARD            $-2.50
```

I would like the regex to match and extract `-10.00% LP` and `LOYALTY CARD`. It will reject the string if it encounters `VOID ALL` or `CANCEL`.

I've got the following regex `(?P<discount_reason>(?!(CANCEL|VOID\sALL)).+) [$|£]?-(?P<discount_value>[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2})` which correctly extracts the discount_reason and discount_value groups, but happily accepts `VOID ALL` and `CANCEL`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a slight modification to your first named capture group:

`(?P<discount_reason>^(?!.*VOID ALL|.*CANCEL).*)`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wA5oG9

Comment: Thanks a million. It works! Could you explain how it works? I'm trying to wrap my head around `(?!.*VOID ALL|.*CANCEL)`.

Comment: It was the `^` anchor that really made it work, but I also made sure to put `.*` into the front of each alternation string within the negative lookahead. It means `"anything... then VOID ALL"`